# How to disable Java Decompiler in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jd-eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Mars 4.5.1 with the Java Decompiler (JD-Eclipse Plug-in v1.0.0).

For a certain class I have the binary file in multiple locations, because I am using 1 workspace for several projects.

JD keeps decompiling this file, but I do have the source code for it. I just can't link it for every binary file, because in some locations it's packaged together with other binaries.

Is there a way to prevent JD from decompiling?

And if not, is there a way to prevent JD from decompiling altogether without uninstalling it?

I already tried disabling it through General -> Startup and Shutdown, but that didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

To stop decompiling you can try to change the default ***.class** file association (do not confuse with ***.class without source**). Navigate to *Window > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations* and for the ***.class** file type change default associated editor from **Class Decompiler Viewer** to **Class File Viewer**.

See [the documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-13.htm) for detailed information.